# Typoscript sitemap with includeNotInMenu items

Tags: typo3, typoscript

I am trying to have the sitemap menu element show specific pages that are set to 'Hide in Menu'.

This is my non-functional typoscript at the moment:

```
tt_content.menu.20.2.includeNotInMenu.override = 1
tt_content.menu.20.2.includeNotInMenu.override.if {
  isInList.field = uid
  value = 981,982
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `includeNotInMenu` is of type boolean, so it has no `stdWrap` functionality with `if`, see: https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/TyposcriptReference/ContentObjects/Hmenu/Index.html . As far as I know there is no way to tell the HMENU object to include only specific hidden pages without creating the menu manually

Comment: You‘ve got a scope problem here: field `uid` holds your sitemap‘s `uid`, not the one of pages being processed in HMENU. That‘s why it wouldn‘t even work when `includeNotInMenu` were stdWrap-enabled.

An approach might be to set `includeNotInMenu` in your HMENU and exclude all TMENUITEMs that have `nav_hide` set and are NOT in your uid list using `doNotShowLink`.

Comment: @undko How do you exclude items based on nav_hide being set?

Comment: @user500665 something like `NO.doNotShowLink.field = nav_hide` should do the trick. You‘ll need "only" whitelisting of allowed uids, then…